# Hosting of let, const

Tags: javascript, executioncontext

```js
/* Hoisting exampe - let */
let a = 100;
{
 console.log(a); // 100
}
{
 console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
 let a = 50;
}
```

```js
/* Hoisting took place in {}. */
{
 let a=100;
 console.log(a); // 100
}
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

First, I know that `let` and`const` have a **block scope**.
Compilation happens in **Execution context** units, and **hoisting** occurs when `LexicalEnvironment` is created.
And the execution context is created by the execution of **global**, **function**, **eval** code.

Shouldn't hoisting of `const` and`let` be done in **global**, **function**, **eval** code units?
(It seems that hoisting doesn't seem to happen, but this is purely thanks to the help of TDZ. Internally both const and let hoisting.)

If engine meet block `{/* code */}` (rather than function) while creating **Execution Context**, are engine adding a new scope for the block to `[[Scope]]`?

Comment: You can find answer for let : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a block is [first encountered](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-block-runtime-semantics-evaluation) (with the `{`), a new execution context [is created](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-newdeclarativeenvironment), which creates a new empty Lexical Environment (which is basically a container mapping variable names in the current immediate scope to their values). The engine then [iterates through](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-blockdeclarationinstantiation) all variables declared with `const` or `let` in the immediate block are initialized. (But, despite being initialized, they aren't referenceable until the engine actually comes across the `const <variableName>` or `let <variableName>` line - the TDZ)

So, plain blocks *do* create a new scope, which will get populated if any statements immediately inside that block declare a variable with `const` or `let`.

You can see this in action with a debugger:

```js
/* Hoisting took place in {}. */
{
    debugger;
    let a=100;
    console.log(a); // 100
}
console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Result in Chrome devtools:

[image]

(though, that's a bit misleading - `a` doesn't actually contain `undefined`, it hasn't been fully created at that point)

The `const` and `let` variable names are hoisted in that the interpreter recognizes *from the start* of the block that it'll be illegal to reference them until they get fully created via the `const` or `let` line.

It's not just plain blocks - *any* level of code will result in the same sort of thing happening (like at the top level, or inside a `for` block, or inside a function).

Comment: Thanks for the very very detailed answer. Images and code help me to understand the text.
However, as I studied more recently, I felt different from CertainPerformance's answer.
CertainPerformance said that **Execution context** also occurs when they meet `{...}`.
**Execution context** is not new, but is it that `[[scope]]` (scope chain) inside **Execution context** provides scope and chaining for information in `{...}` ?